# Authenticate with VSTS / TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm upgrading a C# app that talks to TFS/VSTS to use the latest TeamFoundation sdk.

I would like to connect and have the app prompt for credentials in the same way that Visual Studio does if you use that to connect to TFS.

I've downloaded the latest stable VSTS Api from nuget.org which is:

`microsoft.teamfoundationserver.extendedclient.15.112.1.nupkg`

I also reference assemblies it uses from my VS2017 install, here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`.

I've tried a number of combinations, but can't get it to prompt. My current code looks like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var netCred = new NetworkCredential();
            var basicCred = new VssBasicCredential(netCred);
            var vssCred = new VssCredentials(basicCred);
            vssCred.PromptType = CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded;
            var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(serverName), vssCred);
            server.Authenticate();
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

It doesn't prompt, and instead outputs this exception:

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException:
>   TF30063: You are not authorized to access
>   https://.visualstudio.com/. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
>   remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequestAndGetResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   webRequest, WebException& webException)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation
>   operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.LocationWebService.Connect(Int32
>   connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, Int32 features)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.FrameworkServerDataProvider.Connect(ConnectOptions
>   connectOptions)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.FrameworkServerDataProvider.Authenticate()
>   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.Authenticate()    at
>   VstsAuthTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   S:\VstsAuthTest\Program.cs:line 26

How do I get it to prompt for and cache credentials?

The old version of the TeamFoundation sdk dlls I was using seemed to work ok. The reason I'm upgrading is because the C# app seems to refuse to connect to TFS when installed on a machine with only VS2017 and not VS2015. I was hopeful upgrading to the latest SDK dlls might help solve the connection issue.

---

I've seen this, but it seems out of date and uses classes that are now deprecated. It's also about connecting without a prompt, but the comments include some discussion of how to get a prompt.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials/

I've also seen these samples which appear recent, but which also use deprecated apis.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples

Comment: You should switch to referencing the NuGet package for the VSTS/TFS API SDK and package the dll's with your product. Taking a depencency on the Visual Studio installation is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) with VssClientCredentials.

Simple code:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TFSAPIConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var u = new Uri("https://XXX.visualstudio.com");
            TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(u, new VssClientCredentials());

            collection.Authenticate();
            Console.WriteLine(collection.Name);
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work ok for me, but I am getting reports with logs from a few people using the tool with this code that they still get the same issue. Authenticate()  throws the exception I mentioned in the question, and they don't get shown a prompt for credentials. These users can login to the VSTS web portal and can connect with Visual Studio fine.

Comment: Do you mean they have issue even though after connecting with Visual Studio? Try to clear related credential in credential manager, also clear the cache of TFS\VSTS (path likes C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, and clearing credential manager and the Team Foundation cache didn't make any difference. I tested the tool successfully (with above code) on systems with no VS installed and one with VS2015 and VS2017 installed. Apparently they just have VS2015 installed. That's the only difference I can think of at the moment.

Comment: Could it connect to TFS/VSTS if you specify that user's account in the code?

Comment: I've got a bit of a feeling it might be down to architecture... if the app is run as 32 bit it seems to be more reliable.

Comment: This takes the credentials from the stored credentials. How can I enter the credentials specifically here with username password without the login screen.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=vsts The sample suggested here does not work for the new DevOps. I want a solution with username password without the alternate credentials